# Header content type no funciona

Tags: php, php7, headers

Estoy teniendo problemas con los headers cuando trato de descargar un archivo.
Actualmente lo tengo almacenado en la BD (sé que no es recomendable pero solo estoy haciendo pruebas) y me lo guarda sin problemas, también guardo el tipo de archivo usando "$fileType = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES['file']['type']);".

El problema que tengo es que cuando trato de descargarlo, siempre lo hace como un archivo sin extensión y creo que el problema puede ser que no me entienda el header del content type, pero tampoco sé por qué no lo entiende si en teoría se lo estoy enviando bien.

Este es el código con el que hago la descarga del archivo:

```
<?php
// Me aseguro que venga el ID
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Lo capturo
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
 
    // Me aseguro que sea válido
    if($id <= 0) {
        die('El ID es inválido');
    }
    else {
        // Conexion a la BD
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'solicitudes');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }
 
        $query = "
            SELECT id, archivo, tipo_archivo, FileSize
            FROM solicitudes
            WHERE id = {$id}";
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);
 
        if($result) {
            // Me aseguro que se haya hecho bien la consulta
            if($result->num_rows == 1) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 
                // Headers
                header("Content-Type: ". $row['tipo_archivo']);
                header("Content-Length:". $row['FileSize']);
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= Archivo - ". $row['id']);
 
                // mando a imprimir el archivo
                echo $row['archivo'];
            }
            else {
                echo 'Error! No existe un archivo con ese ID.';
            }

        }
        else {
            echo "Error! Por favor intente de nuevo. Error: <pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
        @mysqli_close($dbLink);
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Error! No se obtuvo ningún ID.';
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué muestra `var_dump($row);`?

Comment: ¿Y porque no le pones la extension aqui?  `filename= Archivo - ". $row['id']`  Una cosa es el `Content-Type` y otra el nombre de archivo

Comment: aarchivo sin extensión es debido a que no le estarías especificando una: `filename= Archivo - ". $row['id'])` salvo que `$row['id']` incluya la extensión ( con punto y todo onda `1.png`, `2.xls`, etc )